# PYQT detect mouse position on widget

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I am trying to get my mouse position on a Widget when clicked. There seem to various methods to do that. The underMouse function seems to be the most popular one. I do not know what I am doing wrong. I tried all the possible techniques. Below is my python code, other than this I have a ui file.

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, uic, QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap, QMovie
import pyqtgraph as qwt_plot
import sys


class Ui(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Ui, self).__init__() # Call the inherited classes __init__ method
        uic.loadUi('stupid.ui', self) # Load the .ui file
        self.show() # Show the GUI
        self.frame = None

        self.timer = QtCore.QTimer(self)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.run)

    
    
        self.track = QtGui.QWidget(self.widget)
    self.setMouseTracking(True)
    self.track.mouseReleaseEvent = self.gig

    def gig(self, event):
    print ("Method 1 worked")


    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):  
        posMouse =  event.pos()
    #print("%d, %d" % (posMouse.x(), posMouse.y()))
    #print (self.track.geometry())
        if self.track.geometry().contains(posMouse):
            print "Under Mouse"
    if self.track.underMouse():
        print ("phew")


    def run(self):
    # Do nothing




if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)  # Create an instance of QtWidgets.QApplication
    window = Ui()  # Create an instance of our class
    window.setWindowTitle('Mouse Position GUI')
    app.exec_()  # Start the application
```

The ui file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>932</width>
    <height>546</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <property name="windowIcon">
   <iconset>
    <normaloff>icon.png</normaloff>icon.png</iconset>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <widget class="QWidget" name="widget" native="true">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>110</x>
      <y>0</y>
      <width>631</width>
      <height>511</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
   </widget>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menubar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>932</width>
     <height>22</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Comment: Please be more careful with [formatting](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362) and indentation, and always check *both* the preview and the published result.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to detect when it is clicked then you must use an eventfilter, you should not assign a function to a method as that method may fail.

```py
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, uic, QtCore, QtGui


class Ui(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Ui, self).__init__()
        uic.loadUi("stupid.ui", self)
        self.show()

        self.widget.installEventFilter(self)

    def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
        if self.widget is obj:
            if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.MouseButtonPress:
                print(self.widget, "press")
            elif event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.MouseButtonRelease:
                print(self.widget, "release")
        return super(Ui, self).eventFilter(obj, event)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Ui()
    window.setWindowTitle("Mouse Position GUI")
    app.exec_()
``
```

Comment: It was showing errors, then I changed self.widget.installEventFilter(self.widget).
Even now nothing is happening.

Comment: @user3141066 What error do you get? I have tested it and it works correctly, do not add more code to my code, if you add it it is no longer my responsibility

Comment: I get this error: TypeError: super() takes at least 1 argument (0 given)

Comment: @user3141066 If you don't provide python version information then I assume you are using the latest version, and obviously the syntax can change from version to version. Try my updated code

Comment: No idea what magic you did, but now it works perfectly. Thanks a lot!